# how to copy all extensions bash script

Tags: bash, copy

So this is probably really easy but I'm new to bash scripts.
I wanted to copy all html files from the directory "/site" to the directory "/checkout/target/site"
I wrote single line of copy code for every one of them but the names keep changing, so I want to write something that copies anything that ends with .html basically
oh and the files might exist in the destination, so overwriting would be a lot better.
Thank you

Comment: See `man cp`, `man find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just in the directory `/site` (not sub-dirs), this makes it:

```
cp /site/*html /checkout/target/site/
```

Comment: wait, it worked once, now I'm getting this error
mv: cannot stat `site/*html': No such file or directory

Comment: In the first moment I understood you wanted to move files, so I wrote `mv ...`. Then I noticed you want to copy them, so I changed to `cp`. If you used the first version of my answer, files are not in `/site/*` now, as they were moved to `/checkout/target/site`. To have them back, just do a `cp` the other way round.

Comment: oh ok. yeah changed to cp as well, and now it works perfectly. Thanks a lot